# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n} =0$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

Show that the following limit holds
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n} =0 
$$
for a fixed value of $k$

I really am just stuck at the first step here. Normally I would consider tackling this using L'Hopitals rule, however $\binom{n}{k}$ is not differentiable. I was considering using the binomial theorem, but that is for sums, not just the single scenario. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I didn't try it but I would suggest writing $n \choose k$ $= \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$ and use Stirling's formula to estimate the factorial.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I tried to clear up what I meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove or disprove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} {n \choose k} / a^n = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z_+}, a \in \mathbb{R}: a> 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788322/prove-or-disprove-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-choose-k-an-0-for-all-k)

Comment: Its not as rigourous as I'd like, but I think its a good enough way for me to think about it, and provides a bound so that I can do out the computations. Thank you

Comment: @wjmccann Note your question, as I state in my comment to zkutch's answer, involves basically showing  there are quite a few posts here that explain, in various ways, that exponentials grow faster than polynomials, e.g., [Is 'every exponential grows faster than every polynomial?' always true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499446/602049) and [Proving exponential is growing faster than polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872848/602049).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept as known $\binom{n}{k} \leqslant \frac{n^k}{k!}$, then you obtain it by estimation.

**Addition**: added second part, as it can be helpful for somebody.
$$\frac{n^k}{k^k} \leqslant \binom{n}{k} \leqslant \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Comment: But even if you don’t accept this, it suffices to accept that it is less than $n^k$. This is indeed true because $n^k$ is the number of ways to pick $k$ objects from $n$ objects with repetition allowed and the order matters. This certainly overcounts the number of ways where we can pick $k$ objects from $n$, but where there are no repetitions and the order doesn’t matter (which is what ${n \choose k}$ represents).

Comment: @zkutch Note this involves the basic case where exponentials (i.e., $2^n$) grow faster than any polynomial (i.e., $\frac{n^k}{k!}$), which you can also prove using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) on the numerator & denominator $k$ times.

Comment: @John Omielan. Sorry, I miss your idea - of course exponent grow faster than any polynomial, but what you want to say? I put simplest way I know.

Comment: @zkutch I was just pointing out not only for yourself, but also for anybody else reading it,  a few extra possibly useful details. I didn't mean to imply anything was wrong with your answer, and I also wasn't asking or expecting you to say anything in particular, which is why I started my comment with "Note".

Comment: @John Omielan. Thanks for explanation. Let me, also from my side, add for such people, that it is possible to say more: $\binom{n}{k} \sim C(k)n^k$ where $C(k)$ depends only on $k$.

Answer (score -2):

Set k = n since it is the greatest it will ever be. The numerator will never surpass 1. So you simply have the ratio of 1 to infinity.

Comment: By $\binom{n}{k}$ I mean "$n$ choose $k$", not $\frac{n}{k}$. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: $k = n$ does not attain the maximum...

Comment: Max is at $k=n/2$

Comment: @mathdoge I misunderstood the question. Didn't read carefully and I was half asleep.