# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^{3.3}} =0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello I just wanted to confirm that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^{3.3}} =0.$$ I have that $\binom{n}{3}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{n^3}{6}.$ So
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^{3.3}}
 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^3}{6}\frac{1}{n^{3.3}}
 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{6n^{.3}}
 = \frac{1}{6} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{.3}}
 = 0.
$$

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Look also at estimation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722962/show-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac-binomnk2n-0/3722975#3722975

Comment: @zkutch, Isn't it the same estimation the OP used? $\binom{n}3\leqslant\frac{n^3}{3!}$?

Comment: @Croissant. As I see, he used equivalence, which is also in link brought $\binom{n}{k} \sim C(k)n^k$, but in comments below. On other hand, of course, estimation is enough.